# Local NS list does not match Parent NS list

Tags: debian, dns, bind

I installed a new BIND server "dns4.clicplus.com" which resolves correctly from the local network and externally. The problem is when I test with:

`# dig @8.8.8.8 dns4.clicplus.com`

Nothing is returned (google dns doesn't know this record). This is also verified using www.mxtoolbox.com dns check:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the rest of the Internet (not using your nameservers) attempts to look up that name (output is from `dnstracer -s . -o -4 dns4.clicplus.com`):

```
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET [.] (198.41.0.4) 
 |\___ m.gtld-servers.net [com] (192.55.83.30) 
 |     |\___ dns1.clicplus.com [clicplus.com] (62.251.202.3) 
 |      \___ dns2.clicplus.com [clicplus.com] (41.137.37.37) 
 |\___ l.gtld-servers.net [com] (192.41.162.30) 
⋮
```

Start with a root name server (the nameservers for `.`) to find the name servers for `com.`. Then from one of those servers, the nameserver for `clicplus.com.`. Then ask one of those nameservers for `dns2.clicplus.com.` (Actually, each nameserver is asked for the full name, but except for the last one, just returns a "go ask that server" response).

You have two big problems (currently—maybe some of this is from backing out the change after it didn't work):

1. You need to tell the gtld-servers about your other DNS servers. dns4 is missing; presumably dns3 should be there as well. This is done via your domain name registrar. If you log in to their website, there should be a place to set DNS servers for your domain. In addition, since the DNS server is under your domain, you need to register the server IP with your registrar, this may be a second step.
2. dns1 and dns2 do not know about dns4 (they say it doesn't exist). You need to make sure to have both `NS` and `A` (and `AAAA` if using IPv6) records for *all* of your DNS servers in your domain. The *same* zone must be loaded on all of your nameservers. Typically, with BIND, this is done by having one master server and the others all transferring the zone from it.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, **1**- I ready talked to the registrar about creating a **glue** **record** (dns4.clicplus.com >> 41.137.108.195) & i add the **A** record in my server as they told me. **2**- actually dns4 I'll be a master server with a different IP Addressing not a slave (so is it possible to setup a two master servers with the same domaine name **clicplus.com**?) thanks again.

Comment: @linuxien master/slave server is just about where BIND transfers the zone from. There isn't any other difference e.g., as far as answering DNS queries. You can definitely have multiple, but then you're responsible for keeping them in sync.